# how to recover a wallet from crashed bitcoin core

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, wallet.dat

I was synchronising for the first time bitcoin core on Mac OSX.
During this never ending process I had the brilliant idea to send some BTC to my wallet from my Kraken account. At some point the app crashed and I never managed to make it continue and finish synchronising. I restarted a new bitcoin core (saved the old, partial one). Now after a week I'm at about 40% (syncing takes another 3 weeks according the app). Where are my transferred bitcoins at this point? how can i get access to them? assuming the bitcoin core synchronising will never end (!) is there another way to retrieve my bitcoins? 
As you can tell I'm a newbie. So bear with me....

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

If you still have the wallet.dat file in the backup from your old bitcoin core, you can still access your funds. Let the new installation finish syncing, then import the wallet.dat using the "importwallet *filename*" command in the debug window console of bitcoin core, or "bitcoin-cli importwallet *filename*" from your computer's console.

Comment: okkk. I'll try as soon as syncing has finished. Thanks a lot! Cheers!

Comment: HI. Bitcoin Core finally (after 3 months!) finished syncing. I tried to import my old wallet file.  But I get 
07:37:53 Cannot open wallet dump file (code -8)   error message.

Comment: Where does the file has to be placed in order to be imported? Can't I just replace the new with the old "wallet.dat" file and reboot Bitcoin Core?